# How to specialize a static function of a class template?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

When I tried to write something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    static void doit();
};

template <>
static void A<int>::doit() 
{
    std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
}

template <>
static void A<double>::doit()
{
    std::cout << "double" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    A<int>::doit();
    A<double>::doit();
}
```

I got a compile error:
[image: The capture of error message]

Specializing the whole class is ok. I just want to know is there any way to specialize only the static function?

Comment: Remove the `static` keyword from definitions

Comment: Note that this is not a *partial* specialization. Members of a class template cannot be *partially* specialized.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki What do you mean? Partial specialization of a member template of a class template [is possible](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1grYANVB9hhowums).

Comment: @Columbo I had member functions and data members in my mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify `static` keyword only once, in declaration.

Try this:

```
template<>
void A<int>::doit() 
{
    std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void A<double>::doit()
{
    std::cout << "double" << std::endl;
}
```